# Keep geom_rect translucent area, but colored outline

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to create an interactive plot with rectangles using plotly in R.

I have the main idea working. However, what I am stuck at is allowing each rectangle to have a colored outline (as delineated in the "fill" column of the data), but an entirely transparent area.

Below is a MWE of what is working:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(Name = paste0("Name",seq(1:10)), xmin = runif(10, 0, 1), xmax = runif(10, 1, 2), ymin = runif(10, 0, 1), ymax = runif(10, 1, 2), fill = sample(c("black","purple"),10, replace=TRUE) )

p <- ggplot(data, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = NULL, colour = fill, text = Name)) + geom_rect(size = 0.3, alpha = 0.5) + scale_colour_identity() + theme_bw()
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
```

I can hover over each rectangle and have the Name variable of the data indicated to me. Moreover, the fill variable of the data decides the color of the rectangles. However, I am unable to make the rectangles transparent.

I tried:

1) Changing fill=NULL to fill=NA, but this results in the error:

```
Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length.out = n) : 
  'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

2) Changing alpha=0.5 to alpha=0.01, but this makes the outline of each rectangle also rather transparent.

Is it possible to create this type of plot only with the area of the rectangles entirely transparent? I am really hoping to keep the outline of the rectangles colored and also able to respond to different alpha values.

If you have any advice for me, I would be very happy to hear it!

Comment: Maybe `geom_rect(..., fill = NA)`

Comment: Make sure you've done `fill = NA` *outside* of `aes` in `geom_rect` as shown in @cuttlefish44 comment.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually simple. Just use a transparent color for the fill parameter using `fill=alpha("grey",0)` for the `geom_rect` function and you will get the desired result.

You can do so by modifying your code as below

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, colour = "purple", text = Name)) + geom_rect(size = 0.3, alpha = 0.5,fill=alpha("grey",0)) + scale_colour_identity() + theme_bw()
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
```

The output looks like
[image: Output Image]